# How do I update the python lib boto?

Tags: python, boto

I am using python's boto script, and I haven't touched in a long time and sort of forgot basic python stuff.

How do I update the script?   I'm not even sure how I installed it so please guide me to figure out what I have to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have `pip` available: `pip install -U boto`

If you have `easy_install` available: `easy_install -U boto`

Otherwise... install `pip`.

Comment: @Blankman: because pip is meant as a replacement for easy_install, see the pip docs for more info: http://pip.openplans.org/#pip-compared-to-easy-install